# RxJava2 merge cached data and subject

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, behaviorsubject

I have an disk storage that returns an `Object?` from disk (Could be already saved or not) and an BehaviourSubject (This data comes from other class call, check code below):

Code is:

```
private val subject: Subject<Optional<Element>> = BehaviorSubject.create()

fun getElements(): Observable<List<Element>> =
    Observable.concat(Observable.just(storage.getElement()), subject)
        .filter({ it.isPresent })
        .take(1)
        .flatMapSingle { 
            Observable.just(it.get())
                .flatMapIterable { it.categories }
                .toList()
        }

fun updateSubject(response: Response) {
    storage.save(response.element) //Save element in storage
    subject.onNext(response.element.toOptional())
}
```

My problem is, in other class I do

```
getElements().subscribe(onElements(), onError());
```

First time, when storage has null it does nothing, even I've got a breakpoint in `subject.onNext(response.element.toOptional())`, hoping that `onNext` will trigger a stream for `getElements`, but nothing happens.
Second time, when I've already saved in storage the received element (So, `storage.getElement()` returns something) it works fine.

My functional description is:

Get element from both cache and subject, take first that arrives, and return it (First time it will be who the comes subject one), next time, i'm hoping that first one will be the storage one.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "first time" and "next time"? Do you mean that you have two subscribers? (one that subscribes before you call updateSubject, and one that subscribes after that?)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that storage is some sort of persistence object so it so `storage.getElement()` might return a valid object at the time you create the subject?

If that is the case, then I think you should check to see if you have a stored object before you create the subject,  if so use `BehaviorSubject.createDefalut(storedObject)` if it does exist or `BehaviorSubject.create()` if not.

Then inside your `getElements()` function I think you can just use `subject.filter()` ....

Comment: I've do it but with same problem, and anyway it should return subject value.

Answer (score -1):

Your null optional elements are being filtered out by your `.filter { it.isPresent }` call so nothing gets emitted downstream.

Comment: Sorry, but subject is receiving a valid value.